# how to display an icon in meteor on click of link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

How to set viewed icon on click of a link in meteor. I have a list jobs page and when user clicks on one job it is going to the description page and what I want is display an icon on the post which tells user that he or she viewed the post.

Comment: Create event and save details to database then show count You can use ajax

Comment: Meteor method to indicate that article has been viewed by user. If the article view flag is set, show the icon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show an icon on click in meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696997/how-to-show-an-icon-on-click-in-meteor)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.events({
    'click .viewed'(event, instance) {
       event.preventDefault();
       instance.$('youriconReference').show();
    },
});
```