# How to show an icon on click in meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I am building an application in a meteor and I have a below code in the template.

```
 <h3>
   <b>
     <a class="viewed" href="/jobdetails/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a>
   </b>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span class="job-type part-time">Part Time</span> 
 </h3>


<div id="eyeIcon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:green"></span>    
 </div>
```

I have to display the glyphicon eye icon on click of a href tag and storing them into a collection. How can I do that? I am new to the meteor. Can anyone help me how can we do it using Meteor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h3>
   <b>
     <a class="viewed" href="/jobdetails/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a>
   </b>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <span class="job-type part-time">Part Time</span> 
 </h3>

{{showIcon}}
<div id="eyeIcon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="color:green"></span>    
 </div>
{{/if}}


Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  'showIcon':  function() {
    return Session.get('showIcon');
  },
});
Template.yourTemplate.events({
  'click .viewed': function(event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set('showIcon', true);
  },
});
```

Please note that I have used session to persist your data throughout the app. If you also want to retain this value permanently than you can use collections.

Also, if you to just retain it's value to be persisted on page refresh also, then you can use Session.setPersistent (https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session) instead of Session.set

Answer (score 0):

Start by hiding your `#eyeIcon` div by default. For example, add the following to `/client/main.css`:

```
#eyeIcon {
  display: none;
}
```

Then leverage the [Blaze Template event system](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-events) to show the div when the link is clicked. So in your Template:

```
Template.yourTemplate.events({
  'click .viewed'(event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    instance.$('#eyeIcon').show();
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is displaying eye icon on click but it's not going to the description page on click. It just displaying icon thats it. How can we solve that issue?

Comment: Your original question just asked about showing the icon. When you say show a description page, do you mean show a description section on the current page, or actually route to a separate page? Are you trying to show the description below the eye icon on click?

Comment: when clicks on one link  it goes to the description page (routes to another page). So when user looks, it should display an eye icon beside to link.